# Rails 3: Validations for object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm creating an object via controller. A `Foo` has many `Bar`s. The `Bar` model has a validation that it must have a `Foo` in order to be valid.

In the `foo.rb` model:

```
has_many: bars
```

In the `bar.rb` model:

```
validates_presence_of :foo
belongs_to: foo
```

In the `foo_controller.rb`:

```
@foo = Booking.new(params[:foo]) # this has all the params needed to make a Foo.
@foo.create_bars(params[:bars])
```

In the `foo.rb` model:

```
def create_bars(bars)
    bars.each do |t|
      bar = Bar.create({name: name, email: email, foo: foo})
      bar.foo = self
      self.bars << bar
      bar.save
      puts self.bars.to_s
    end
  end
```

The `puts self.bars.to_s`

This sounds like it should be something really basic, but since the `foo` doesn't exist in the db, does ActiveRecord consider it to be nil, and that's why it's not saving? How can I write this properly?

Comment: did you try working with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ? it really looks like this would be the way to go for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this part first:

> This sounds like it should be something really basic, but since the
>   foo doesn't exist in the db, does ActiveRecord consider it to be nil,
>   and that's why it's not saving? How can I write this properly?

Not quite. The validation doesn't depend on anything in the database, it merely checks whether the specified field (or dependent object) is present in the model before persisting. The `create` method is a kind-of shortcut that not only initializes an ActiveModel object, but also simultaneously attempts to save it in the database. Your validation is failing because you're calling this method BEFORE you've set the `foo` field of your `bar` object.

You **can** technically use `create` in this instance by passing `foo: self` in your scenario, but frankly I would go with @pablopablo89's answer in regards to this part. If you do it this way, when you save `Foo`, all the `Bar` objects will also get saved.

Additionally, the `.create` method for creating `Bar` objects is dangerous because, since you're immediately persisting `Bar` objects independent of the parent `Foo`, if for whatever reason your `Foo` cannot be saved (fails some other validation, etc etc), you end up with a bunch of orphaned `Bar` objects with no way to remove them independent of a `Foo` (I'm making a bit of an assumption of how your system actually works). Assuming this is a reflection of your system, the goal you want to keep in mind is that an object, and all of its dependencies, are saved in one atomic operation. If one fails, they all fail, and you alert the user.

To answer the question more generally, as @phoet pointed out in the comment, you might be a lot better off changing your form and using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method. Here is the [link to the rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

In the `Foo` model, add the line `accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars`, and then use `fields_for` in the form, something like this:

```
<%= form_for @foo do |f| %>
    ...other stuff...
    <%= f.fields_for :bars do |f_bar| %>
       ... bar-related stuff ...
```

The submitted parameter map will return with all the bar-related stuff within the `:foo` key in such a way that it will create both the `Foo` object, and all of the related `Bar` objects all at once. In that scenario, `create` will also work, although I still tend to do separate `.new` and `.save`, but its up to you.

[This link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) regarding how to use `fields_for` might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this:

```
def create_bars(bars)
  bars.each do |t|
    self.bars << Bar.new({name: t[:name], email: t[:email]})
  end
end
```

<< operator used for active record objects sets association automatically.

Do not forget to add has_many :foos, and belongs_to :bar in the models.

Answer (score 0):

Booking.new just initializes an object. In order for foo to exist you need to save it. Once you save it your validation while creating bar objects will pass and the objects should be created. Hopefully this should work